# How to close all tabs in VsVim

Tags: visual-studio, vsvim

I'm trying out VsVim after using ViEmnu.

In ViEmnu `:qa` will close all tabs, but in VsVim `:qa` closes Visual Studio. When it is relaunched, all tabs remain open.
According to [this issue](https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/issues/1131), this is by design.

Is there a way of closing all tabs in VsVim, without closing Visual Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this point in time there is no way.  Primarily because there doesn't appear to be a method in Vim for me to emulate in VsVim.  If there is I would eagerly like to hear about it so that I can implement it.

There are plans to implement `tabonly` though.  That is close to the request as it closes all but the current.

> https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/issues/1131

Answer (score 3):

I've created an alias to a Visual Studio command to do this.

In the file `%HOMEPATH%/.vsvim`, I've added the following line:

```
map <leader>q :vsc Window.CloseAllDocuments<CR>
```

Now, pressing `\q` will close all open tabs.